# I want to differentiate partially a vector variable function. My code didn't work

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions

I want to differentiate partially a vector variable function.

```
f[v_] := v[[1]]^2 + v[[2]]^3;
D[f[v], v[[1]]]
```

This code didn't work.

Please give me an idea.

```
f[v]
```

returns

```
Part::partd: Part specification v[[1]] is longer than depth of object.
Part::partd: Part specification v[[2]] is longer than depth of object.
v[1]^2 + v[2]^3
```

Comment: what happens if you type `f[v]` on its own? (from clean kernel)

Comment: what is `v` supposed to be? Can you give an actual working example?

Comment: @Nasser I typed f[v]. Then the above error occurred.

Comment: @Nasser v is supposed to be a list.